# How to Get Array Index in Google Sheet with CHOOSE Function

Tags: function, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have data like this

[DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VePBP.png)

I want to choose the data into 2 columns with google spreadsheet function `CHOOSE`

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},$A$1:$A$3,$C$1:$C$3
```

But it will result like this

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Z4XR.png)

it's only show the first row of the data, how can I fix it to get the whole data?

I think have a problem with the array but I tried some combination of array function it still doesn't work

---

edited

I want to get `VLOOKUP` with multiple criteria like this one
[Vlookup multiple criteria](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08qP4.png)

Comment: Can [choosecols](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914) serve the purpose here with something like `choosecols(A1:C3,1,3)`?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow but I want to make some 'like' concatenate with `$A$1:$A$3&"|"$B$1:$B$3` because I want to take `VLOOKUP` with multiple criteria

Comment: @RadhwaRamizalhaq What is your actual goal? You can do lookup using multiple criteria without concatenating them.

Comment: @Harun24hr doing vlookup with multiple criteria

Comment: @RadhwaRamizalhaq Can you edit your post and show desired result by `VLOOKUP()`?

Comment: I have edited the post with desired result @Harun24hr

Comment: @RadhwaRamizalhaq Please see my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get selected columns use `CHOOSECOLS()` function.

```
=CHOOSECOLS(B2:D4,1,2)
```

To get values as concatenated, use-

```
=INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(B2:D4,1) & "|" & CHOOSECOLS(B2:D4,2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After edit of OP's question. Use `FILTER()` function instead of `VLOOKUP()`.

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,B2:B4=B7,C2:C4=C7,D2:D4=D7)
```

[image]